# Trying to Create Order through Order API

Tags: nopcommerce

I am getting this error when attempting to create an order

```
"order placement": [
      "Order GUID is not generated"
    ]
```

I have looked through the code for API and this error is not generated in that project.

I attempted this and it didnt work either

```
 [JsonProperty("order_guid")]
        public Guid OrderGuid { get; set; }
```

This is the section in the CreateOrder Endpoint where the error is generated

```
        var placeOrderResult = PlaceOrder(newOrder, customer);

        if (!placeOrderResult.Success)
        {
            foreach (var error in placeOrderResult.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("order placement", error);
            }

            return Error(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
```

Seems like the error is being thrown in the nopCommerce not the API

Can I get some help around this?

Comment: can i ask you to send the code behind the "PlaceOrder" function?

Comment: I actually figured out and made the change to my local copy of the API.  The OrderGuid was not being created, during the ProcessNewOrderRequest.